# error while trying to use jar inside c++ code using JNI : libjvm.so not found

Tags: java, c++11, makefile, java-native-interface, ubuntu-16.04

I have a jar file named Untitled.jar that prints some text message. It has a void function call giveMeString() and the class name is xegerImplementation.

giveMeString() generates string for the regular expression defined inside the giveMeString(). I needed to generate strings given a regular expression in c++. Since java has a library called xeger that does this, so I thought to create a jar and then import that inside the c++ code.

I have implemented the following code which I got from https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/specs/jni/invocation.html and tweaked it to match my jar file.

The cpp file name is **main.cpp** and has the following code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "jni.h"
int main(){
    JavaVM *jvm;       /* denotes a Java VM */
    JNIEnv *env;       /* pointer to native method interface */
    JavaVMInitArgs vm_args; /* JDK/JRE 9 VM initialization arguments */
    JavaVMOption* options = new JavaVMOption[1];
    options[0].optionString = "-Djava.class.path=/home/aaa/Desktop/Untitled.jar";
    vm_args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_8;
    vm_args.nOptions = 1;
    vm_args.options = options;
    vm_args.ignoreUnrecognized = false;
/* load and initialize a Java VM, return a JNI interface
 * pointer in env */
    JNI_CreateJavaVM(&jvm, (void**)&env, &vm_args);
    delete options;
/* invoke the Main.test method using the JNI */
    jclass cls = env->FindClass("xegerImplementation");
    jmethodID mid = env->GetStaticMethodID(cls, "giveMeString", "(I)V");
    env->CallStaticVoidMethod(cls, mid);
/* We are done. */
    jvm->DestroyJavaVM();
}
```

When I was using **g++ main.cpp -o main** to generate the executable main file. But it gave me the following error :

```
/tmp/ccf3LtdA.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x5d): undefined reference to `JNI_CreateJavaVM'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Then with the help from stackoverflow, I was able to solve this error by compiling it with the following code:

```
g++ -g -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/include/ -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/include/linux/ -L/usr/bin/java -L/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/server/ main.cpp -o main -ljvm
```

It generates the executable main file.

Then, I tried to run the executable main file with the following command

```
./main
```

It gives me the following error:

```
./main: error while loading shared libraries: libjvm.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I tried to add the path to libjvm.so to the  LD_LIBRARY_PATH. But still it doesnot work.

What am I doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated.

**Update 1 :**
I copied the libjvm.so file to the /lib folder of ubuntu. Now it finds the error libjvm.so file and the error is gone. 
**Now there is a new type of error :**

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/Object
```

When I do echo $JAVA_HOME it gives me the following :

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
```

java -version is also working correctly.

**Update 2 :**
The problem was occuring because I had not setup the LD_LIBRARY_PATH correctly. Now I set it to `$JAVA_HOME/lib/amd64:$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/amd64/server` And this solved the problem of libjvm.so not found.

Comment: How did you set **LD_LIBRARY_PATH**?

Comment: @AlexCohn I did the export LD_LIBRARY_PATH and it seems to be blank when I echo. So I copied the libjvm.so file to the lib folder of linux kernel. Now, it finds the libjvm.so but the problem is it gives me error Error occurred during initialization of VM
java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/Object

Comment: Make sure to instal JDK not just JRE. It looks like your class path is somehow mixed up.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was occuring because I had not setup the LD_LIBRARY_PATH correctly. Now I set it to $JAVA_HOME/lib/amd64:$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/amd64/server And this solved the problem of libjvm.so not found.

Answer (score 0):

I'd have started with simple code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "jni.h"
int main(){
    JavaVM *jvm;       /* denotes a Java VM */
    JNIEnv *env;       /* pointer to native method interface */
    JavaVMInitArgs vm_args; /* JDK/JRE 9 VM initialization arguments */
    JavaVMOption* options = new JavaVMOption[1];
    options[0].optionString = "-Djava.class.path=.";
    vm_args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_8;
    vm_args.nOptions = 1;
    vm_args.options = options;
    vm_args.ignoreUnrecognized = false;
    JNI_CreateJavaVM(&jvm, (void**)&env, &vm_args);
    delete options;
    jvm->DestroyJavaVM();
}
```

to make sure that your JVM is properly configured.

From error message, it looks like `rt.jar` file is not on class path.

I'd be careful with moving `libjvm.so` to `/usr/lib` or `/lib`.

Take a look here for a sample code where Java is called from C:

http://jnicookbook.owsiak.org/recipe-no-027/

You can also use `-rpath` while linking your C++ to make sure your lib is always found while running code.

Comment: I am not looking for multithreaded application. I have a jar file which I want to make use in c++. The problem exactly occurs at JNI_CreateJavaVM function. I tried providing the jar file location in the class path. To make sure that it finds I even ran the jar file from terminal and it runs but somehow it doesnot run in this JNI

Comment: But - can you run code above? Without JAR in class path? Does it work? The code above will, at least, give you hint whether issue is related to JAR or classpath of JDK.